# Sort in access database

Tags: sql, ms-access

Im trying to sort a database in access and I can't get it done. I need to use only the records with the latest day. First the city with the lowest price and all the prices of that city, then the city with the second lowest price, etc. Thank you!!

This is the example database:

```
Date           Country    City     Price    Departure_date     Return_date
05-06-2019     Peru       Lima     360$     xxxx               xxxxx
05-06-2019     Peru       Lima     420$     xxxx               xxxxx
05-06-2019     Mexico     CMX      300$     xxxx               xxxxx
05-06-2019     Mexico     CMX      400$     xxxx               xxxxx
05-06-2019     Mexico     Cancun   350$     xxxx               xxxxx
05-06-2019     Mexico     Cancun   500$     xxxx               xxxxx
05-06-2019     Peru       Cusco    50$      xxxx               xxxxx
05-06-2019     Peru       Cusco    60$      xxxx               xxxxx
04-06-2017     Mexico     Cancun   300$     xxxx               xxxxx
04-06-2017     Peru       Cusco    70$      xxxx               xxxxx
04-06-2017     Peru       Cusco    30$      xxxx               xxxxx
```

It has to be sorted this way:

```
Date         Country    City     Price    Departure_date     Return_date
05-06-2019   Peru       Cusco    50$      xxxx               xxxxx
05-06-2019   Peru       Cusco    60$      xxxx               xxxxx
05-06-2019   Mexico     CMX      300$     xxxx               xxxxx
05-06-2019   Mexico     CMX      400$     xxxx               xxxxx
05-06-2019   Mexico     Cancun   350$     xxxx               xxxxx
05-06-2019   Mexico     Cancun   500$     xxxx               xxxxx
05-06-2019   Peru       Lima     360$     xxxx               xxxxx
05-06-2019   Peru       Lima     420$     xxxx               xxxxx
```

Comment: What's wrong with answer already provided in your other question? [Sorting in access database with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62053921/sorting-in-access-database-with-multiple-columns).

Comment: Hi June, I added a new column with dates and I wanted to include it in the code but I didn't get a response in the other question that I edited.

Comment: Answer in that other question has been revised.

Answer (score 1):

There is likely to be a way to condense this, but the following should perform as required:

```
select t0.*
from 
    YourTable t0 inner join
    (
        select t1.city, t1.date, min(t1.price) as mprice
        from 
            YourTable t1 inner join
            (
                select t2.city, max(t2.date) as mdate
                from YourTable t2
                group by t2.city
            ) t3 
            on t1.date = t3.mdate and t1.city = t3.city
        group by 
            t1.city, t1.date
    ) t4 
    on t0.city = t4.city and t0.date = t4.date
order by 
    t4.mprice, t0.city, t0.price
```

Essentially:

- The innermost subquery (`t3`) obtains the records for each city with the latest date (`mdate`).
- The outer subquery (`t4`) obtains the minimum price (`mprice`) within the set of latest records for each city.
- Finally the main query outputs the relevant records, sorting by minimum price (to sort the city groups), then by the `city` (to sort cities with the same minimum), and then by the `price` to sort records within each city group.

You will need to change all occurrences of `YourTable` to the name of your table.